# How to integrate Azure Active Directory with Identity Server 3?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, identityserver3, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Identity Server for implementing single sign-on and access control. Currently I am using internal(in DB), OpenId and Google as for single sign-on and access control.We have one a requirement to use Windows Azure AD users for the same.Is this possible to authenticate with Azure AD using the Identity Server, and should be able to update role and claims on Azure Active Directory?
I have found one solution i.e. Graph API but it is not part of Identity Server (https://identityserver.github.io).
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using identity server 3 then ws-federation can be used for authentication and roles. You can use following two links to understand it more.
for ws federation authentication:
http://nzpcmad.blogspot.in/2015/12/identityserver-aspnet-mvc-application_7.html

For creating role for the users:

http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/

However if you want to update also the user information, you have to use graph-api

Answer (score 0):

You need to add azure active directory authentication middleware in your application pipeline at your STS server for Azure active directory having all required standard properties.